# How to make android debug stable?

Tags: android, debugging, adb

Usually when I debugging my application and run code step by step , the debugger will lost connect. It happens very often in complex operation code. So how to make the debug stable?

Answer (score 0):

You may compile `GDB` for statically and push it on device,
and then you may run debugger right on your device.